# form tag disappear in foreach loop razor MVC 3

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a problem with form tags in a foreach loop in razor when it render the output html is wrong because in the first iteration the form tags disappear here is the razor code

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
        {



            <tr>

                <td>@if (item.IsMandatory)
                    {
                        <span class="label label-important">Obligatorio</span>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <span class="label">Opcional</span>
                    } </td>

                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DocumentName)</td>
                <td>



                </td>
                <td>
                    <form>
                        form here!
                    </form>

                </td>
             </tr>

        }
```

here is the rendered html:

```
 <table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
     <tr>
         <th>Requerido</th>
         <th>Documento</th>
         <th>Accion</th>
    </tr>
</thead>    
 <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
      <span class="label label-important">Obligatorio</span>
     </td>
     <td>Copia de cédula</td>
      <td>
       here form!    <----------Problem Here
      </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>
     <span class="label label-important">Obligatorio</span>
     </td>
      <td>
        Copia de otro documento de identidad (licencia, pasaporte, seguro)
     </td>
      <td>
        <form novalidate="novalidate">
                 here form!
         </form>

      </td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Your rendered HTML contains a `form` tag.

Comment: not in the first iteration, it only contais a form tag in the second <tr>, not in the first

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably trying to start a new  tag inside an existing one, like this:

```
<form id="mainPageForm">
@foreach(item in items)
{
    <form id="nestedForm@(item.FormId)">
}
</form>
```

Which results in something like this:

```
<form id="mainPageForm">
  <form id="nestedForm1"></form>  --> this ends the first form
  <form id="nestedForm2"></form>  --> correctly formed
  <form id="nestedForm3"></form>  --> correctly formed
</form> --> closing tag without parent
```

Comment: So how did you get round this problem?